# Invoke secured method from Spring controller without authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4, Spring Data REST, Spring Security. I created a `@Controller` mapped to a specific path that doesn't require authentication because it used from a sms gateway for report incoming texts.

So I've just to create a controller to read those parameters and then save the text on the db. And here there is the problem. To store data I use repositories that are secured, while in the controller I've not any kind of security (in fact I cannot ask the provider to secure its calls).

I tried to set an authentication context programatically but seems not working:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/inbound")
@Transactional
public class InboundSmsController {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/incomingSms", produces = "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1")
public ResponseEntity<?> incomingSms(@RequestParam(name = "Sender", required = true) String sender,
        @RequestParam(name = "Destination", required = true) String destination,
        @RequestParam(name = "Timestamp", required = true) String timestamp,
        @RequestParam(name = "Body", required = true) String body) {

    log.info(String.format("Text received from %s to %s at %s with content: %s", sender, destination, timestamp, body));
    setupAuthentication();

    try {                       
        int transitsWithSameTextToday = transitCertificateRepository.countByTextAndDate(body, Instant.now()); //This is the method that raises an Auth exception
....
....
} finally(){
   clearAuthentication();
}


SecurityContext context;

/**
 * Set in the actual context the authentication for the system user
 */
private void setupAuthentication() {
    context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN");
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("system", "ROLE_ADMIN", authorities);
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
}

private void clearAuthentication() {
    context.setAuthentication(null);
}
```

The method `countByTextAndDate` is annotated with `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`

I'm surprised also setting the Auth context I've this error. Am I doing something wrong? Is this the best way to reach my goal?

I don't want to annotate my method with `@PermitAll` because that method is also exposed by Spring Data REST and I don't want anyone can use that.

Comment: Just setup security as you normally would (that way you have an authentication, an anonymous one but nonetheless authorization) and write a security rule for that specific party. Like `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() || hasIpAddress(<the-explicit-ip-address-from-the-sms-gateway>)")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `AccessDecisionManager`'s RunAsManager. Here's the link that could help you with this :
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-run-as-auth

Happy Coding!!!